# Rails Doesn't Recognize Parameters POSTed from Ruby Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails controller with a `create` method, and I want to POST to it from a Ruby script. When I hit this method from a browser-based POST, the `params` hash is set appropriately, but when I hit it from my script, the hash is empty. I've already disabled protect_from_forgery, and the method does get called; it just has an empty `params`. Here is the controller method:

```
def create
  logger.info "GOT: #{request.body.read}"
  logger.info "PARAMS: #{params.inspect}"
  az = AreaZip.new(params[:area_zip])
  if az.save
    respond_to { |format|
      format.js { render :json => {:id => az.id} }
    }
  else
    logger.warn "FAILED creating AreaZip: #{az.errors.inspect}"
    respond_to { |format|
      format.js { render :json => {:errors => az.errors} }
    }
  end
end
```

Here is the code that does the posting:

```
def self.post(url, path, params={})
  url = "#{url}#{path}"
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  headers = {
    'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization' => "Basic #{Base64.encode64('censored:censored').strip}",
  }

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  post_data = params.map {|k,v| "#{CGI::escape(k.to_s)}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}" }.join("&")
  resp, data = http.post(uri.path, post_data, headers)
  return JSON.parse(data)
end
```

Here is what I see if I post to `nc -l -p 12345`:

```
POST /admin/area_zips HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Basic sdfnjjsadf[censored]jklsdfsjdfkj
Content-Length: 54
Host: localhost:12345

area_zip%5Bzip%5D=15068-4838&area_zip%5Barea_id%5D=334
```

If I post to my Rails app, my log shows this:

```
Started POST "/admin/area_zips" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Jul 29 09:45:05 -0400 2011
  Processing by Admin::AreaZipsController#create as */*
Asking for HTTP basic authentication to reach admin page
GOT: area_zip%5Bzip%5D=15068-6851&area_zip%5Barea_id%5D=334
PARAMS: {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"admin/area_zips"}
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
FAILED creating AreaZip: #<OrderedHash {:area=>["can't be blank"], :zip=>["can't be blank"]}>
Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 41.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

So as you can see, Rails gets the POSTed data, but it's not using it to set up `params`. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried not escaping your params? I'm not so sure you need escaping other than in plain URLs, not in post data. Also check out the `Net::HTTP` docs for recommended ways to do POST: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html

Comment: Params actually are supposed to be escaped in a POST, and I can see that my browser is escaping them when it sends the data. I tried unescaping anyway, though, and it didn't fix things.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the docs. I never noticed that basic_auth method before. That means I don't have to send my own headers, and that means I can use the set_form_data method instead of my other approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I solved this. Turns out the problem was the Content-Type header. I need to set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Actually I thought I was doing this, but apparently not. That old Content-Type value was a copy-paste error, leftover from the code in my `get` method.